# Eilenberg-Mac Lane functor being an embedding

Tags: category-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

So, I'm reading Rognes's paper *Galois Extensions of Structured Ring Spectra* and was wondering about one of his claims. In the beginning of section 4.2 he says the following:

> The Eilenberg–Mac Lane functor $H$, which to a commutative ring $R$ associates
>   a commutative $S$-algebra $HR$ with $\pi_*HR = R$ concentrated in degree 0, embeds the category of commutative rings into the category of commutative $S$ -algebras.

What does "embedding" mean in this context? That the functor $H$ is fully faithful? Although I can see that this functor is faithful, it is not obvious to me that it is full (if it is). Is the Eilenberg-Mac Lane functor a full functor between the category of commutative rings to the category of commutative $S$-algebras?

It seems to me that different authors use the notion of "embedding" differently, so I just want to make sure that I am not stuck trying to prove something that is not true...

Comment: As far as I know, it's fully faithful.

Comment: Do you have a good reference for it being full?

Comment: What kind of homs are you taking in $S$-algebras? This should be homotopically full, but not literally, since $S$-algebras are spectra, right-the spaces involved are big-you're never going to get, say, a finite space of morphisms.